# When the Lie algebra of matrices with zero last rows is Frobenius?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, frobenius-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}_{n,k}$ be the Lie algebra of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ for which the last $k$ rows are equal to zero. Suppose that $k$ does not divide $n$. How to prove that $\mathcal{A}_{n,k}$ is not a Frobenius Lie algebra, i.e., that for every form $l \in \mathcal{A}_{n,k}^*$ the bilinear form $\langle a, b\rangle = l([a, b])$ is degenerate?

(For the case when $k$ divides $n$ I know the proof that it is Frobenius.)

Comment: And how does the proof that you know go?

Comment: One can construct a certain non-degenerate form $l$ when $k$ divides $n$. See http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.1193v1.pdf for example.

Comment: Hmm. Your $\mathcal{A}_{N, M}$ there is a different Lie algebra. Are they conjugate?

Comment: Yes, they are isomorphic.